# Can a Delegate Apply to Two VCs

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I think I'm using protocols in a way that shouldn't work... but it does. Can someone tell me if what I'm doing is okay?

**Example**

Let's say my app has three view controllers: MainView, SecondaryView, EditorView. The EditorView has buttons that should run code in the other views. I have a protocol which allows me to trigger functions remotely.

Here's the weird thing, the thing I'm doing that maybe I shouldn't... but it's working: Both MainView and SecondaryView conform to the same protocol. I don't understand why it works, but it does.

When I am in MainView and I load the EditorView and, for example, click "Add", the code in the MainView runs and works.

When I am in SecondaryView and I load the EditorView and click "Add", the code in the SecondaryView runs and works.

**Question**

If this is okay, how is it figuring out which (Main vs Secondary) to delegate to? If it's not okay, why is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not only okay - it's great. You've discovered one of the primary benefits of protocols.

In `EditorView` you have a `delegate` property (you might've named it something else):

```
weak var delegate : EditorProtocol?
```

You also have some code somewhere in `MainView` and `SecondaryView` that looks like:

```
let editor = EditorView() // or perhaps you get it in prepareForSegue(_:sender:)
editor.delegate = self
```

That tells `EditorView` which object to communicate with.

Then within `EditorView` you call code like:

```
delegate?.doSomething()
```

If `MainView` created this editor, then `delegate` is a `MainView`. Otherwise, it's a `SecondaryView`.

When you set `delegate` (or whatever you named it) to a specific object, that's what `EditorView` will communicate with.

Comment: this not good example when user forget set delegate value, App must be crash

Comment: @LokeshDudhat It is a good example and it actually answers the question. And forgetting to set the delegate will not cause a crash. Of course the app may not work as desired but it won't crash.

Comment: I forgot that when I followed the guide to implement protocols that I did add code to the prepareForSegue (let editorVC = segue.destinationViewController)!! So that's how the Editor knows who to delegate to. Very cool. This is great, thanks.